# LGA 1150 and Haswell Refresh CPU's

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

Many of the LGA 1150 motherboards, will not support some or all of the Haswell Refresh CPU's, even some of the H97 and Z97 it seems according to the vendor specifications (specifically in regards to the i5-4690K and i7-4790K). Having contacted one of the manufacturers (Gigabyte since they didnt require a signup etc...) they will make no guarantee about what BIOS revision the boards are currently retailing with, leaving almost no boards guaranteed to support these CPU's...

In the event that the delivered motherboard (UK Retailers) has an older BIOS revision, what are my options (in the UK)? Can I take it somewhere? Can I get my retailer to fix it (or at least to replace with another board that is updated)?

I understand even a Z87 with an older BIOS can not be flashed using an unsupported CPU.

Comment: Sorry, but service recommendations are off topic on superuser.

Comment: So shall i rewrite this as "i have x cpu and y motherboard, now what to do?", cause its still an issue...

Comment: That is a good idea.